# Need Regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I have tried a lot to write a regular expression for below line but could not get the success, so requesting some body to help me out in this.

**Exp: "APStress_May-15---11.20.3_UIlog".**

In the above example APStress and UIlog will be fix rest of the things will  get change. i.e

**Month ->May,
date -> 15,
Hour -> 11,
Minute ->20,
Seconds ->3**

I am writing a script for analysis the logs for that i have to choose this particular file among others .

Comment: have you tried `APStress.*UIlog` ??

Comment: @ abasu .. thanks Man .. :) it is working as per my need .

Comment: Welcome :) I was under impression that there might be more problems associated with it, so commented first, now posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`APStress.*UIlog`. Here `.*` denotes any characters any number of times. Here is an useful link for your future reference. http://www.regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
APStress_(.*?)-(\d{1,2})---(\d{1,2}).(\d{1,2}).(\d{1,2})_UIlog
```

(not necessarily the best way of doing it)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`APStress_([\w]+)-([\d]+)(-){3}([\d]{1,2}).([\d]{1,2}).([\d]{1})_UIlog`

Answer (score 0):

You could use named capture groups:

```
/^APStress_(?<Month>\w+)-(?<Date>\d{1,2})---(?<Hour>\d{1,2}).(?<Minute>\d{1,2}).(?<Seconds>\d{1,2})_UIlog$/

dump%+
```

**outout:**

```
("Hour", 11, "Month", "May", "Date", 15, "Seconds", 3, "Minute", 20)
```